# angular2 using Dragula can't reorder multiple tbody's

Tags: angular, dragula

My angular2 dragula setup for those who are interested can be found here:
[How to set up angular-quickstart with ng2-dragula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759895/how-to-set-up-angular-quickstart-with-ng2-dragula)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Dragula Table Issue</h1>
        <table class='container'>
            <tbody *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [dragula]='"other-bag"'>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i}}</td>
                    <td>{{item}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>      
        </table>
    `,
    viewProviders: [DragulaService],
    styles: [`\n\

    `]
})
export class AppComponent { 
    public items:string[];

    constructor(){
        this.items = new Array();
        this.items[0] = "zero";
        this.items[1] = "one";
//        this.items[2] = "two";
//        this.items[3] = "three";
//        this.items[4] = "four";
//        this.items[5] = "five";
//        this.items[6] = "six";
    }
```

The above renders the following html for the table, which for example purposes is what I want:

```
<table _ngcontent-uqa-1="" class="container">
            <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "zero,one"
}--><tbody _ngcontent-uqa-1="" ng-reflect-bag="other-bag">
                <tr _ngcontent-uqa-1="">
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">0</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">zero</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody><tbody _ngcontent-uqa-1="" ng-reflect-bag="other-bag">
                <tr _ngcontent-uqa-1="">
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">1</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">one</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>      
        </table>
```

However after dragging the first row after the second row we see that the table row from the first tbody, is moved into the the tbody of the second:

```
<table _ngcontent-uqa-1="" class="container">
            <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "zero,one"
}--><tbody _ngcontent-uqa-1="" ng-reflect-bag="other-bag">

            </tbody><tbody _ngcontent-uqa-1="" ng-reflect-bag="other-bag">
                <tr _ngcontent-uqa-1="">
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">1</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">one</td>
                </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-uqa-1="" class="">
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">0</td>
                    <td _ngcontent-uqa-1="">zero</td>
                </tr></tbody>      
        </table>
```

So how do I move the tbody's around as a block rather than just the tr's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dragula** is working like this. If you add it to a tag, it will use **drag and drop** with the first level children of that tag. In your case you add it to the `tbody`, so it will use **drag and drop** with `tr`'s. So you need to add the **drag and drop** to the table.

```
<table class='container' [dragula]='"other-bag"'>
            <tbody *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" >
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i}}</td>
                    <td>{{item}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>      
        </table>
```

and change the `*ngFor` to solve your problem